# Constructing minimal supplements with GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, computer-algebra-systems

The problem is this:

> Suppose we are given a finite group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ which is not contained in $\Phi(G)$. Call a subgroup $H$ of $G$ a **minimal supplement** for $N$ (in $G$) if $G=NH$ and $G>NM$ for every proper subgroup $M$ of $H$. Given, $G$, $N$, what is an *efficient* way of constructing a minimal supplement for $N$ in $G$ with GAP?

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a difficult problem in general.

One method that should work for moderately sized groups is to start by finding representatives of the conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups of $G$ using the function $\mathtt{ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups}$. Then create a list $\mathtt{L}$ say of those maximal subgroup representatives that do not contain $N$. Since you are assuming that $N \not\le \Phi(G)$, the list $\mathtt{L}$ will be nonempty.

Now repeat the following process. Find representatives of the conjugacy classes of maximal subgroups of $\mathtt{L[1]}$, and make a list $\mathtt{LL}$ of those groups in $\mathtt{L}$ that supplement $N$. If $\mathtt{LL}$ is nonempty then replace $\mathtt{L}$ by $\mathtt{LL}$ and repeat. When $\mathtt{LL}$ is empty, you know that the current $\mathtt{L[1]}$ is a minimal supplement.

This should find you a minimal supplement moderately quickly. If you wanted all minimal supplements (up to conjugacy), then it would be more difficult, because you would have to do these calculations for every group in each list $\mathtt{L}$.

If $N$ happened to be abelian, then all supplements would intersect $N$ in a normal subgroup of $G$, so another approach might be to find the normal subgroups $M$ of $G$ that are properly contained in $N$, and find complements of $N/M$ in $G/M$, using the function $\mathtt{ComplementClassesRepresentatives}$.

Here is some GAP code for the procedure above.

```
MinimalSupplement := function(G,N)
  local max, supp, oldsupp, gN;
  max := MaximalSubgroupClassReps(G);
  supp := Filtered(max, x -> not IsSubset(x,N));
  if Length(supp) = 0 then
    Error("Normal subgroup lies in Frattini subgroup");
  fi;
  gN := GeneratorsOfGroup(N);
  while Length(supp) > 0 do
    oldsupp := supp;
    supp := MaximalSubgroupClassReps(oldsupp[1]);
    supp := Filtered(supp, x ->
              G = Subgroup(G, Concatenation(GeneratorsOfGroup(x),gN)) );
  od;
  return oldsupp[1];
end;
```

Comment: I wonder if we can do any better than that. For example, if $|N|$ is relatively small, then your suggestion is perhaps the only way to go. (But maybe one could check first if $N$ has a complement in $G$.) What if it is, instead, relatively large? Can we work from the bottom up?

Comment: (I will wait a bit before accepting since I was actually hoping for some GAP code.)

Comment: This already has a detailed description of the process. What the first point where you stop while trying to put this into the GAP code?

Comment: OK, on this occasion, since I had more or less done this already, I will post some GAP code for the procedure I described. I am not really a GAP expert, so it is possible that it could be improved. I agree that it would be a good idea to check for the existence of complements first, but as far as I know that is only possible when $N$ is solvable. I agree with Alexander that is not in general reasonable to ask people to write GAP code for you.

Comment: I think "MaximalSubgroupClassReps" will shorten the code a bit.

Comment: Yes, I've done that.